# Make region fullscreen in PRISM application by stretching user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating application using PRISM library. Currently i had only one region. Inside this region i put a user control with my view (as you can see below). Is just a some menu with property grid and a list to display data.

My  user control:
 [image: user control]

By default my main window is full screen. When I run my application there are some remaking blank space below my user control.
[image]

Question:
How i can stretch my user control to fill all available space? As on picture below

[image]

What i've done:
- My user control container currently is DockPanel i tried put it to grid and other controls
- Delete user control sizes (width and height)
- Use viewbox inside shell.xaml (it destroys everything)
- Put user control to different cotainers inside shell.xaml

Currently shell.xaml is my "main window" I has only window tags with my user control.

I find similar questions on stack overflow but nothing helped me.

--- UPDATE ---
This is example of my user control code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NewPrj.View.FullScreenTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<DockPanel Background="Blue" LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Something"/>
    </Menu>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid Grid.Column            = "1"
                           >
        </xctk:PropertyGrid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

This is my shell.xaml window

```
<Window x:Class="NewPrj.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewPrj"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="New Prj" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
</Grid>
```

And this is actual result:

[image]

As I said before, there are many related topics but it does not work.

Comment: Please post your XAML markup for the window and the user control(s).

Comment: Put your UserControl inside of a Grid inside of the window.  Nothing at all to do with MVVM, Prism, etc.

Comment: I put user control inside grid of the window before i ask this question. The problem is that did not work. I also tried to create some rows for Grid as You can read in related topics. Tomorrow I will post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason:

This was not fully stretched because i use **ItemsControl** which use **stack panel** as default data template

Solution:

Change data template of ItemsControl or use User Control instead

```
<UserControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
```

[I found answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700701/wpf-getting-verticalstretch-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks, this was annoying until i found your post.